# Контактная форма на Bootstrap не посылает форму

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap

я использую Контактную форму на Бутстрап с Валидацией и Каптчей. Все работает, как должно работать, но сама форма никогда не приходит на эмэйл. Попробовал доменный эмэйл и свой хотмэил, ни туда ни туда форма не приходит. В чем может быть проблема? Стараюсь решить вопрос с формой уже очень давно и все никак не выходит, был бы очень признателен если кто то мог бы помочь пожалуйста

ajax

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#contact_form').on('submit', function (e) { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_contact.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {              
            var message_type = 'alert-' + response.type;
            var message_text = response.message;
            var message = '<div class="alert ' + message_type + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + message_text + '</div>';
            if (message_type && message_text) {
                $('#contact_form').find('.messages').html(message);
                $('#contact_form')[0].reset();
                grecaptcha.reset();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;       
})
});
```

Forma

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <h2>Bootstrap Contact Form with Captcha using PHP & Ajax</h2>
          <form id="contact_form" method="post" action="process_contact.php" role="form">
            <div class="messages"></div>
            <div class="controls">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
                    <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter message *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld..."></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Php

```
    <?php
require('recaptcha/src/autoload.php');
$from_email = '<ale>';
$send_to_email = '<ale>';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$form_fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 
'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message');
$mail_send_suceess = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back 
to you soon!';
$mail_send_failed = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again 
later';
$recaptcha_secret_key = '6Ld...';
try {
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
    }
    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptcha_secret_key, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());
    $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
        throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha was not validated.');
    }
    $message_body = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($form_fields[$key])) {
            $message_body .= "$form_fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from_email,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from_email,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from_email,
    );
    mail($send_to_email, $subject, $message_body, implode("\n", $headers));
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $mail_send_suceess);
}
} catch (\Exception $e) {
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $mail_send_failed);
}
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $encoded;
} else {
echo $responseArray['message'];
    }
```

Comment: А проверяешь локально или как? Если локально - то вероятно у тебя не установлен никакой отправитель почты. Также функция `mail` возвращает результат работы, его тоже можно проверить.

Comment: Проверял после залития всех файлов на хостинг, в поля куда отправить пробовал вставить и доменный эмэйл и hotmail. Ни туда ни туда форма не приходит